# Volunteering for a not for profit - is there anything for SharePoint I can get for my company cheaper?

Tags: 2010, third-party-software

I'm doing some volunteer development for a not for profit organization. I know there are a few companies I've seen around the place that offer their software for free to not for profits (e.g. Balsamiq). Are there any that do the same for SharePoint related software?

Comment: What do you consider as SharePoint related software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft administers a volume license program for qualified charitable organizations.  If you have not engaged a Microsoft Partner or Microsoft themselves in regards to this, that would be my first stop.

You can also check http://www.techsoup.org, Software is donated and can be applied for there.

If there is a specific add/on or service you are interested in, I would open a dialog with that vendor directly.  They will probably give it to you or at a deep discount with some concessions (such as putting on your website you are using their tech).

Answer (score 1):

Some companies offer discounts for educational institutions from my experience. If there is a particular need you need to fill, like workflow, evaluate the 3rd party offerings, then talk to their respective sales folks. They might not give it away for free, but you might have to pay annual maintenance or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

you can try SharePoint Foundation as far as i know it is free but the features are limited. maybe you can consider this. but please do take note that the server is on premise therefore you still need to spend for the hard ware.